# conversión a fecha campo de texto

Tags: sql, postgresql

Recibo un csv que viene con varios campos:

| id | cod | time | value | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4587 | 2022-12-03 | 0.457 | 20221203_130003 |
| 2 | 4588 | 2022-12-03 | 0.625 | 20221203_130003 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

el campo `created` se corresponde con la fecha en que fue creado el fichero.

Puede pasar que la fecha en la que fue creado el fichero sea distinta del campo `time`.

Lo que quiero es convertir el campo `created` en tipo `fecha` para poder hacer posteriormente la comparación de ambos campos, si coinciden el valor del campo `time` con el del campo `created`, entonces cojo ese `id`.

He probado a usar

```
select id, cod,time, TO_DATE(created, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS time2 from csv_load
```

Pero el resultado es un error del tipo

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "20221203_130003" SQL state: 22008
```

Pensé en hacer primero un **substring** del campo **created** del modo

```
Select id , cod,time, substring(created,1,8) AS TIME2 FROM csv_load
```

Ahora el campo **time2** tendría la cadena correspondiente a la fecha del campo **time**

| id | cod | time | value | time2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4587 | 2022-12-03 | 0.457 | 20221203 |

pero me faltaría darle el formato fecha.

Me he venido arriba y he probado a meterle a la primera sentencia un `to_date` pero...

```
select id , cod,time, substring(created,1,8) AS TIME2 to_date FROM csv_load
```

error... alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes probar con la funcion `to_date` pasándole el formato `YYYYMMDD`

```sql
SELECT id , cod,time, TO_DATE(substring(created,1,8), 'YYYYMMDD') to_date FROM csv_load
```

por ejemplo:

```sql
test=# select TO_DATE(substring('20221203_130003',1,8), 'YYYYMMDD');
  to_date   
------------
 2022-12-03
(1 row)
```

Comment: GRACIAS @domingo y @Anthony Sotolongo he decidido usar la segunda opción pq la primera me daba problemas. A mayores he modificado el campo a timestamp without time zone para que fueran más iguales `SELECT id , pacode,time, TO_TIMESTAMP(substring(created,1,8), 'YYYYMMDD')::TIMESTAMP to_date FROM csv_load`

Answer (score 1):

Usando CONVERTER y CAST para volverlo fecha, cuenta con estilos definidos, no se pueden personalizar, sin embargo cuenta con 112 yyyymmdd, el cual será útil para tu caso, igual te comparto un enlace con los formatos que maneja https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp.

Te comparto el código basandome en el ejemplo que proporcionaste:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUBSTRING('20221203_130003', 1, 8), 112) AS DATE);
```